# How do you toggle off Visual Studio Code's Developer: Inspect TM Scopes command?

Tags: visual-studio

I can toggle the command on from the Command Palette, but how do you toggle it back off?

Answer (score 1):

Close the file and open it again (or just switch to another and back).

Comment: Well, that does work, but it's not the toggle on/off I was hoping for.